# how to create drop shadows in Qt stylesheet?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, stylesheet

My impression on drop shadows before was that, it's done with images having drop shadows already. Until I found out that you could create drop shadows using plain CSS. How do you create drop shadows though in Qt stylesheet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For QFrame you can set the frameShadow property, but not via CSS. QGraphicsView has the QGraphicsDropShadowEffect class. In a QWebView you can use all CSS effects, but only be using CSS stylesheet in the content.